# Does JavaScript have a similar capability as LINQ's Select statement?

Tags: javascript, c#, .net, linq, select

Say I have an array of window objects and each has an ID property and I need to get an array of those IDs.

In LINQ, I would just do this...

```
var ids = windows.Select(window => window.id).ToArray();
```

Nice and simple.  But in Javascript, I've been doing this...

```
var ids = [];

for(i = 0; i < windows.length; i++)
{
    var window = windows[i];
    ids.push(window.id);
}
```

I'm just wondering if there's a simpler/easier way in Javascript, similar to LINQ's elegant solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are happy with IE8 and above support, [array.map()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) is a comparable option:

```
var ids = windows.map(function(val) {
    return val.id;
});
```

This of course becomes even more succinct (and similar to LINQ) if using ES6 fat arrow functions, although this will require a transpiler if supporting non-cutting edge browsers:

```
var ids = windows.map(x => x.id);
```

Comment: Transpiler? What be dat?

Comment: ES6 syntax is not supported by most browser builds (yet).  Transpilers are wonderful tools that rebuild the syntax into something consumable by more browsers.  They allow you to write in one syntax and output in another.  Common examples would be Babel or Traceur.

Comment: "Most browsers"? Well, Apple is the glaring exception, but [even Microsoft supports arrow functions](http://caniuse.com/#feat=arrow-functions) if you are using Edge rather than IE. (And of course Chrome and FF do.)

Comment: This is for a Chrome extension. Do you know if that supports ES6?

Comment: @nnnnnn "using edge rather than IE".  Well, I'd say that excludes a fair market share then :)

Comment: Sure does. But "most browsers" and "most users" are different categories... (But no, I wouldn't use arrow functions in production code.)

Comment: @nnnnnn which is why I specifically said "most browsers" and not "most users".  You'll still be limited in previous builds and most IE versions as well as small-market player browsers.  I'm not speculating on user distribution...only that you have to be aware of your target browsers.

Comment: @nnnnnn when dealing with browser support (particularly for corporate/enterprise applications), yes, i count each IE version as a separate browser, unfortunately.  Plus like I mentioned, there's the myriad of small-time browsers that are still catching up, not that they're worth considering 99% of the time.  The lesson is still "be aware of your target demographic", semantics aside.

Comment: Oh, sorry, deleted my last comment before I saw your reply. I agree with "be aware of your target demographic", and as it happens in my work I do have to allow for IE10, and 9 sometimes. (Still, I'd say "leading edge" rather than "bleeding edge".)

Comment: @nnnnnn a fair point perhaps.  We may be more "cutting edge" than "bleeding edge" now in regards to fat arrows :).